# Google Analytics Phonegap v1.9

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics

Hi all i have integrated GA into my phonegap 1.9 project. I got it working about 3 days ago when i saw sessions in my GA account. However, it does not seem to show any more sessions or active users. Can someone tell me what is the repairing timeframe to show stats 48hrs? also how do i get it working to show realtime usage. thanks.

ps. in my LogCat i see its being started successfully and appears to be tracking...

```
        window.plugins.analytics.start("UA-XXXXXXXX-1", function(){console.log("Analytics: start success");}, function(){console.log("Analytics: start failure");}) 
        window.plugins.analytics.trackPageView("index.html", function(){console.log("Track: start success");}, function(){console.log("Track: failed");});
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you see the logs you have in your code, you should see the statistics right away. Go to your analeptics home page, Click on `Home` next to the "Standard Reporting", then click on `Real-Time`, the click on `Overview`. If you wrote the UA-ID and everything properly, you should see the usages right away ...

In `iOS` and `Titanium`, there is 20 seconds delay because of API implementation, but I am not sure about `PhoneGap`.